# jQuery next modal img opacity animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made modal window for my img gallery. I want to animate opacity changing of next/prev images inside modal. When i click "next" button i want next modal images fade in smoothly, changing opacity from 0 to 1. At the same time i want current img fade out smoothly too. 
Please, give me advice how i can achive this? 
Now, when i click next/prev button i change opacity of images in gallery, not inside modal.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ETJB9/8/)

HTML

```
<div id="content">


    <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="modal-close">Close</div>



        <div class="btnModal-left">Prev</div><!--end btnLeft-->
  <div class="btnModal-right">Next</div><!--end btnRight-->        

    <img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/5d7b5eedccc289bd332af80a1ad5a226/montero-2017-us.jpg"><br>
    </div>



</div><!--.modal-content-->


  <ul class="gallery">

<li><img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/a1289c4c6916baabb98e4673c7052f8/2014-hyundai-veloster-reflex-chicago.jpg"></li>

<li><img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/a039929c8405451173090144693c1fa0/vw-grc-beetle-chicago.jpg"></li>

<li><img src="http://o.aolcdn.com/dims-shared/dims3/GLOB/crop/1280x850+0+0/resize/628x417!/format/jpg/quality/85/http://o.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/adam/1799bb1e072b82bda13c81563bdf5d0f/01-lingenfelter-reaper-chicago-1.jpg"></li>

 </ul>   

  </div><!--#content-->
```

CSS

```
ul.gallery {
position: relative;
display: block;
width: 100%;
}

.gallery li {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}

.gallery li img {
display:block; 
position:relative;
width:100px;
height:70px;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 10px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    height:350px;
    width:500px;
}


.btnModal-left, .btnModal-right  {
display:inline-block;
border:1px solid black;
 }


.modal-content img {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    max-height:350px;
    max-width:500px;
}


.modal-close {
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
right: 15px;
top: 15px;
width: 40px;
height: 20px;
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
border:1px solid black;
opacity:1;
}
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var сlicked;    

 $(".gallery li").click(function() {

        $(".modal-content").fadeIn();

          $('.modal-content img').attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));

 сlicked = $(this);

}); 

    $(".modal-close").click(function() {

        $(".modal-content").fadeOut();


}); 

    $('.btnModal-right').click(function(){

    сlicked.find('img').fadeOut().end().next().find('img').fadeIn().trigger('click');



});

$('.btnModal-left').click(function(){
 сlicked.find('img').fadeOut().end().prev().find('img').fadeIn().trigger('click');


}); 



});
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: My working example here http://jsfiddle.net/ETJB9/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/pznnj/1/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var сlicked, clone;

    $(".gallery li").click(function () {
        clicked = this;
        $(".modal-content").fadeIn();
        var clone = $(this).find('img').clone(true);
        clone.css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        $('.modal-content').append(clone);
        clone.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 1000);
    });

    $(".modal-close").click(function () {
        $(".modal-content").fadeOut();
    });

    $('.btnModal-right').click(function () {
        if ($(clicked).next('li').length) {
            nextImage = $(clicked).next('li').find('img');
            clicked = $(clicked).next('li');
            nextClone = nextImage.clone(true);
            nextClone.css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $('.modal-content').append(nextClone);
            nextClone.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                $(this).prev().remove();
            });
        }
    });

    $('.btnModal-left').click(function () {
        if ($(clicked).prev('li').length) {
            prevImage = $(clicked).prev('li').find('img');
            clicked = $(clicked).prev('li');
            prevClone = prevImage.clone(true);
            prevClone.css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            $('.modal-content').append(prevClone);
            prevClone.animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 1000, 'swing', function () {
                $(this).prev().remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Rob, thank you very much! It's working perfect for me and it exactly what i wanted to achive.

Comment: Can i ask you one more question? I tried to make responsive modal window and put code for responsive img and block. Pics resized perfectly on small screen, but modal window not. ( I made red border to modal for to show clearly what i need). I put media queries to change modal height. But i think its wrong way. If possible, give me some idea how i can achive this via jquery (if it can be done via jquery). I tried $('.modal-content'). width(clone.width()); but it doesn't work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/pznnj/2/

Comment: @Lucky your media queries seemed to be commented out in the demo.  What exactly seems not to be working?

Comment: Rob, thank you for answer! You code above working perfect. My problem starts when i tried to make modal window responsive. I made new demo http://jsfiddle.net/pznnj/4/ with all styles. When i try to resize browser window to small screen,  you can see that modal img resize proportionally, but modal content block stay the same width and height. I tried to control modal content height via media queries, but i think its wrong way. Tried to make something like $('.modal content').width(clone.width()); but its not working. How i can force modal content change size on small screen?

Comment: You were almost correct with your demo yesterday but you had your media queries commented out in the CSS!   Have a look here and play with how you want it to look. http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/pznnj/5/

Comment: Rob, thank you very much for answer! I commented media queries in last demo because i was thinking that i was wrong and i should calculate modal content height only in js. But now i see that i was almost on right way. But i forgot that i can use % to calculate width and height. Its much more better! Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to add fadeout after next() and need to use this like following example

```
$(this).find('img').end().next().fadeOut();
```

Comment: Hi Ramzan, thank you for answer! But when i use this code and press Next button  all images dissapeared! http://jsfiddle.net/ETJB9/11/ Can you show edit in jsfiddle, please?

Comment: Thank you to all who answered my question, special thanks to Rob!

Answer (score 0):

[Check Out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mE8d/)

You want to fade out the original image and tap into the OnComplete event before changing the IMG source and fading back in.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var selectedItem;

    $(".gallery li").click(function () {
        selectedItem = $(this);
        $(".modal-content").fadeOut(500, function() {
            // Change the IMG source and fade in AFTER the fade out is complete.
            $('.modal-content img').attr('src', selectedItem.find('img').attr('src'));
            $(".modal-content").fadeIn();    
        });
    });

    $(".modal-close").click(function () {
        $(".modal-content").fadeOut();
    });

    $('.btnModal-right').click(function () {
        selectedItem.find('img').end().next().find('img').trigger('click');
    });

    $('.btnModal-left').click(function (){
        selectedItem.find('img').end().prev().find('img').trigger('click');
    });
});
```